# jQuery and "water floating" effect

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

**EDIT: As a member pointed out the problem here below seems to happen in Safari, not in Firefox.
Any idea why ?**

I'm studying a code found online in order to make div appear like floating on water.
The original code is here:
https://codepen.io/ScottPolhemus/pen/xsgco

I played with it and made it as simple as possible :
https://jsfiddle.net/7krv20bx/1/

And here is the code :

```js
$(function() {
  makeConfetti(3);

  $('.confetti-pixel').each(function() {
    var x = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
    var y = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
    $(this).css({
      'transform': 'translateX(' + x + '%) translateY(' + y + '%)'
    });
  });
});

function makeConfetti(num) {
  $('.confetti-layer').append(new Array(num + 1).join('<span class="confetti-pixel"></span>'));
}
```

```css
.confetti-pixel {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: 10s confettiDrop ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.5%;
  margin: 8% 2.5% 0;
  padding-bottom: 2.5%;
  animation-delay: (10s * 2 / -3);
  background: black;
}

.confetti-layer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes confettiDrop {
  0% {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="confetti-layer"></div>
```

So far so good. but I need to create my own spans while the code is generating them automatically. So, I started to just add manually in the HTML a few

```
<span class="confetti-pixel"></span>
```

This way, I get a few manually added spans and a few automatically generated ones so that I can see how the scripts reacts.
But then, the scripts only animates the automatically generated ones, not the ones I added manually.

Here is the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7krv20bx/

I don't understand why since the "makeConfetti" function only adds spans, it shouldn't do anything in terms of animation. So, it feels to me like the animation should impact ALL the spans as long as they share the same class, not only those generated by the MakeConfetti function.

My ultimate goal is to have no automatically generated spans and to get rid of that 'MakeConfetti" function. But if I do so, the spans are not animated.

Can I ask you why ?

Thank you.

Comment: I see 6 animated spans in the fiddle

Comment: Your answer intrigued me so I ran the jsFiddle on both Safari (my default browser) and Firefox. And in Firefox they are all animated alright while only the last 3 spans are animated in safari. Do you have an idea why it is so ? Any prefix I need to add somewhere or something ?
PS: I edited my original post according to your comment. Thanks.

Comment: So you can now post the answer yourself

Comment: I hesitated because you helped me a lot but I can't mislead people by considering your post as the answer because it's not about the "-webkit" prefix after all.
Still, I thank you very much.

Comment: I deleted my post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mplungjan's guidance, I came to realize that it might be an "after load" problem. So I simply got rid of the "$(function{})" wrapper and now it works in all browsers.

Why is Safari not complying? I don't know.

Will it be an issue in other circumstances? Maybe.

But in this case, it worked.

FYI: adding "-webkit" to the CSS and JS didn't change anything. It wasn't about that.